# Error Installing Xamarin.Forms Nuget package in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

Good Day eveyone. I'm currently installing Xamarin.Forms Nuget Package but I repeatedly get this error whenever I trying to to install it.

***Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'http://nuget.syncfusion.com/xamarin/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms''***

I was able to install other packages but not this one. How can I solve this? Here's my printscreen. [image]

Comment: you need to set your nuget feed to https://www.nuget.org/api/v2

Comment: @Jason how do I do that Sir?

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of nuget are you running. You may need to try updating NuGet.

If that does not work or it is already updated, try to install the NuGet package using the Visual Studio **Package Manager Console** instead: In Visual Studio -> View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console

Then type: `Install-Package PACKAGENAME -ProjectName PROJECTNAME` You may need to repeat that for each project you want to install the package into.